# Настройка изображение товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, интернет-магазин

Здравствуйте! Может кто-то поможет? У меня в магазине (на витрине) размер товара отображается в зависимости от написания названия товара (количества знаков). В результате, если название длинное блок с изображением увеличивается и получается волнистая горизонталь.[image: вот такая кривая витрина]. Т.е. блоки резиновые.
Если кто-то знает, как зафиксировать изображение в WOOcimmerce (выровнять по одной линии), ПОМОГИТЕ!

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо задать высоту заголовка с названием товара. Все зависит от того, какая тема у вас установлена, но общая идея примерно такова:

```
h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title {
  height: 2.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Тема у меня Llorix one lite. Буду пробовать. Главное,. направление задано.